# ERR_CACHE_MISS: going to previous page need reloading

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am building a website using GAS, after logging-in with a valid user name and password, everything seems to work fine, when returning to previous page, the page fails to load with an error regarding `ERR_CACHE_MISS`.

To be able to actually load the page i need to refresh, causing a less smooth flow.

Any ideas?

I tried to disable cache from the console, it actually solves the problem, but once the console is closed the problem comes back.